# Par e impar em php

Tags: php

tenho que fazer um código php para mostrar a soma dos numeros pares, impares e soma total,e também a quantidade de pares e impares. Porém quando clico no botão ele muda o numero, e não armazena nem soma.EX: Quando digito 10, ele aumenta a quantidade de par, porém quando eu coloco outro número, por exemplo 5,a quantidade de pares vai a 0 e a de impar aumenta. Alguém sabe como resolver? Segue o código abaixo:

```
     <form action="at2.php" method="post">
    <label for="num">Digite um número </A></label><br>
    <input type='number' name='num'><br>
    <button type="submit" name="btn_enviar"> CALCULE </button><br><br>            
         
  
  <br><br>
  
  <?php
 if(isset($_POST['btn_enviar'])){
 $arr = $_POST;
 array_pop($arr);
 $pares = array();
 $impares = array();

foreach ($arr as $value) {
  if(fmod($value,2) == 0){
    $pares[] = $value;
  }else{
    $impares[] = $value;
  }
}
$psum = array_sum($pares);
$isum = array_sum($impares);
echo "Quantidade Pares " . count($pares) . "<br>";
echo "Quantidade Impares " . count($impares) . "<br>";
echo "Soma  Pares: " . $psum . "<br>";
echo "Soma  Impares: " . $isum . "<br>";
echo "Soma Total: " . ($psum + $isum) . "<br>";
 }

  ?>
```

Comment: O protocolo é *stateless*, o que significa que ele não retém o estado de uma requisição para outra. Se você precisa que a entrada do seu programa seja um formulário HTML, você terá que persistir esses valores em outro lugar que não na memória da aplicação. Você pode persistir em arquivo (até através das sessões, se preferir) ou em um serviço externo, como um banco de dados.

Comment: Acho que sua abordagem deveria ser de enviar todos os números na request para ser calculado uma única vez. Mas se você quer enviar os números individualmente, você precisa salvar de alguma forma os dados que vai precisar pros futuros calculos ou, você pode ter um javascript no front-end que vai acumular os números pra enviar de uma vez para o back-end (e, também, mostrar uma prévia das contagens, se quiser)

Answer (score 0):

Toda vez que você aperta o botão 'Calcule' você inicia o processo do zero e reinicia as variáveis:

Para que uma variável se mantenha a mesma em varias requisições diferentes, deverá usar as variáveis de sessão, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<form action="at2.php" method="post">
<label for="num">Digite um número </A></label><br>
<input type='number' name='num'><br>
<button type="submit" name="btn_enviar"> CALCULE </button><br><br>            
     

 <br><br>

 <?php
   session_start();

   if(isset($_POST['btn_enviar'])){
   $arr = $_POST;
    array_pop($arr);
    //  $pares = array();
    //  $impares = array();

    foreach ($arr as $value) {
     if(fmod($value,2) == 0){
       $_SESSION['pares'][] = $value;
     }else{
       $_SESSION['impares'][] = $value;
     }
    }
   $psum = array_sum($_SESSION['pares']);
   $isum = array_sum($_SESSION['impares']);
   echo "Quantidade Pares " . count($_SESSION['pares']) . "<br>";
   echo "Quantidade Impares " . count($_SESSION['impares']) . "<br>";
   echo "Soma  Pares: " . $psum . "<br>";
   echo "Soma  Impares: " . $isum . "<br>";
   echo "Soma Total: " . ($psum + $isum) . "<br>";
```

Comment: Opa, funcionou amigo. Muito obrigado